# react doesn't display images from laravel project

Tags: laravel, reactjs

I'm new using laravel and react.

I have a laravel API witch contains articles. These articles are food recipes that have a title, a description and an image.
However when I'm using react and the images doesn't appear...

My ItemDetail.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const apiLink = 'http://localhost/laravel/laravel-intro/public/api/article';
class ItemDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.location.state) {
            this.setState(this.props.location.state);
        }
        else
            this._getData();
    }
    _getData = async() => {
   fetch(`${apiLink}/${this.props.match.params.number}`).then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsondata => {
            this.setState(jsondata.data[0]);
        });
    };   
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <strong>Título: </strong>{this.state.title}
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <strong>Descrição: </strong>
                        { this.state.description }
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <strong>Categoria: </strong>
                        { this.state.name }
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        { this.state.image }
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <Link to={{pathname: '/'}}>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary">Voltar</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ItemDetail;
```

Gives me the following error.[image: error]

Comment: The error is in `components/App.js` not in `ItemDetail.js`. Read the error message.

Comment: You're right, I try to put a logo image in the app.js and it doen't work. The image is in the laravel poject and gives that error.
I'm going to put the app.js code below.

Answer (score 0):

The app.js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import List from "./List";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import ItemDetail from "./ItemDetail";
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="panel panel-default">
                        <div className="panel-heading">
                            <h1>Hoje para jantar</h1>
                                <a href={require("/docs/source/assets/images/chef.jpg")}></a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="panel-body">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path='/' component={List}/>
                                <Route path='/item/:number' component={ItemDetail}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default App;`
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending request from ReactJS to PHP, you should manage CORS errors, else You will get errors while sending requests, so create one file named Cors.php file inside the Middleware folder (app/http/middlewares/Cors.php). and write the bellow lines of permissions in the Cors.php as follows:

```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;
   use Closure;
   class Cors
      {
       /**
           * Handle an incoming request.
           *
           * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
           * @param  \Closure  $next
           * @return mixed
         */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
          //ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
              return $next($request)
             ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"*")
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, 
       DELETE, OPTIONS')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, 
   Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
   
    }
 }
```

Now call the Cors.php file inside Kernel.php using this line of code \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class. (app/http/Kernel.php).